# Use java S2I for spring boot app with gradle build in openshift

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, openshift

How to get started with java S2I build for spring boot application with Gradle build?

Please suggest me any Json/yml file needs to be imported to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a whole repo - https://github.com/dsevost/gradle-s2i - with a Dockerfile to build a S2I gradle builder image, and a [template](https://github.com/dsevost/gradle-s2i/blob/master/openshift/springboot-gradle-s2i-template-1.yaml) to build applications on top of it.

Perhaps it is worth noting the `BUILDER` parameter in the template with possible values of 'Gradle' or 'Maven'. According to the [`assemble`](https://github.com/dsevost/gradle-s2i/blob/master/docker/s2i/bin/assemble#L27) script, it will build a gradle project even when both `pom.xml` and `build.gradle` are present in the project directory.

I haven't tried it myself but I glanced over the template and it looks OK...assuming the image and S2I scripts are functional.

Comment: Thank you. Just to glance I can copy past the YML into openshift yml/JSON importer and can start the S2I build?

If it isn't too much to ask, do you mind helping me how to get it done from scratch since I am novice openshift user?

Comment: I really need serious help, Please guide me on the same and I can't understand the repo files.

Comment: Hi @Prash. Assuming you have proper access to an OpenShift cluster, run one time only the commands described under https://github.com/dsevost/gradle-s2i#build-from-scratch up to and including `oc new-build...`; this will build a new builder image you can use as base for your gradle-built apps. For every app you want to build, replace in the `oc new-app...` command that follows the arguments as appropriate - `oc new-app -h` will list all options. Don't execute the last `oc new-app...BUILDER=maven...` command - that is to build an app using maven.